# java script working on one condition

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

i am working on an html base application and i have 2 popups that opens when i trigger a  button

this is the code for the first popup:

```
<div id="id01" class="modal" style="padding-top:150px;">

    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" style="width:80%; height:70%;     border-radius: 25px;" >


        <div class="container" style=" padding-left:13%; border-radius: 25px; padding-top:10%; ">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name "  style=" padding-top:15px; color:black; width:90%; text-align:center; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-top:none; border-bottom:solid;  border-width:0.1px; border-color:#b3b3b3; "/><br />

            <input  type="password" name="name" placeholder="Your passwored "  style=" padding-top:10%; color:black; width:90%; text-align:center; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-top:none; border-bottom:solid;  border-width:0.1px; border-color:#b3b3b3; "/><br />

            <br>



            <select  style="border-style: none;  background-position: center;     background-size: 150% 150%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(file:///android_asset/images/loginbtn1.png); text-align:center; width:90%; height:30px;   border-radius: 25px; "><p>    </p>
                <option style="display: none;" ></option>

                <option value="student">Saab</option>
                <option value="instructor">Saab</option>

            </select>

            <img src="file:///android_asset/images/loginbtn2.png"  style=" padding-top:10%; margin:auto; text-align:center; width:90%; height:auto;  ">

         </div>


    </form>
</div>


<script>
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
modal1.style.display = "none";

   }




}




</script>
```

this is the code for the second popup:

```
<div id="id02" class="modal" style="padding-top:150px;" >

    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" style="width:80%; height:70%;     border-radius: 25px;" >



     </form>
</div>




<script>
// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick = function(events) {
    if (events.target == modal2) {
modal2.style.display = "none";

   }


}





 </script>
```

i am using the following code that is triggered from a button for each popup the are opening fine

my problem is that when i try to click outside the body the first code works fine and it closes but the second one does not close it sticks on the page and doesn't close

thank for your help in advance.

Comment: `i am using the following code` - there is no code after this statement? Did I miss something>

Comment: yes but its just adding an onclick() to open the popups but its working fine the problem is closing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overwriting your handler function. Try using one function

```
if (event.target == modal1) {

}else if(event.target == modal2){

}
```